# Does Twill Work With HTTPS?

Tags: python, twill

I just got Twill and was playing around with it, and it seems to have trouble with HTTPS sites. For example, the command **go('http://boston.craigslist.org/')** will connect just fine, but **go('https://accounts.craigslist.org/')** fails. The same thing occurred when trying to connect to other HTTPS links, but HTTP links have no problems

[image: works fine]

[image: does not work]

Comment: In your question text, please provide a traceback of the error you receive showing the failure when using HTTPS.

Comment: I suspect that this is a problem with a redirect.  However, the fact that twill re-raises the exception makes it hard to tell.  A quick way to find out would be to edit browser.py (perhaps doing a non-root install of some kind first) to change that raise at line 122 to just a plain no-arguments raise, so that the original exception from the mechanize library is visible.  Alternatively, turn on printing of HTTP traffic to see which request goes wrong (mechanize has that feature, and I assume it is exposed in twill somewhere).

Comment: Also: try a different https: URL, with a different domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, opening https: scheme links is supported by twill.